# Ember js: parentViewDidChange doesn't get triggered

Tags: view, ember.js

If have a little game where images have to be dragged on the right hotspots of a larger image.

The little images are inside a containerView, the hotspots also are ContainerViews.
When i drop the images on a hotspot i use the following code in my drag-n-drop mixin to move the image in the dom:

```
Player.Droppable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    drop: function(event) {
        //get the view that was dragged
        var viewId = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
        var view = Ember.View.views[viewId];

        //log the parent-view: App.AnswerListView
        console.log(view.get('parentView').constructor);

        //detach the view from the original containerView
        var parentView = view.get('parentView');
        parentView.removeObject(view);

        //attach it to the hot-spot-containerview
        this.addObject(view);

        //logging this gives a different result: App.HotspotView
        console.log(view.get('parentView').constructor);

        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The view i'm dragging is an App.AnswerView. What i'm expecting from the docs is that the function parentViewDidChange on the AnswerView is triggered, but that doesn't happen:

```
App.AnswerView = Ember.View.extend(App.Draggable, {
    templateName: "answer",
    classNameBindings: [':answer', 'this.content.isSelected:selected'],
    click: function(evt){
        this.get('controller').send('answerClicked', this.content);
    },
    parentViewDidChange: function(){
        this.get('controller').send('answerMoved', this.content);
    },
});
```

The docs say: Called when the parentView property has changed. In my case, it is changed. Is this a bug, or am I missing something here?

TIA

Comment: It would be great if you provide an example jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net), or at least mention what version of Ember are you using, as different versions sometimes have differences in their API.

Comment: Hi George, i've put up a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/eqNdb/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was a bug and got resolved in the 1.0.0 final 
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2423

Answer (score 0):

pushObject and removeObject are methods, inherited from the Ember.MutableArray Mixin, that the Ember.ContainerView extends. If you look at Ember's source code for ContainerView (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.2/packages/ember-views/lib/views/container_view.js#L15), you will see that ContainerView does not override those methods, thus they only manipulate its childViews array, not the view's parent view.
You should find methods that manipulate the '_parentView' property here instead: (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.2/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L2018) - in the Ember.View's implementation. 
So in short, use:

- removeChild instead of removeObject, to delete a child view from your ContainerView
- createChildView + pushObject instead of 'addObject', if you want to add a new child view to a ContainerView.

Example Code:

```
Player.Droppable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    drop: function(event) {
        //get the view that was dragged
        var viewId = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
        var view = Ember.View.views[viewId];

        //log the parent-view: App.AnswerListView
        console.log(view.get('parentView').constructor);

        //detach the view from the original containerView
        var parentView = view.get('parentView');
        parentView.removeChild(view);

        //attach it to the hot-spot-containerview
        this.createChildView(view);
        this.pushObject(view);

        //logging this gives a different result: App.HotspotView
        console.log(view.get('parentView').constructor);

        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx for the input! I've changed the functions, but the event still doesn't get triggered. When I log the parentView variable it changes. I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eqNdb/4/

Comment: You are right... It does not get called, although it should. I advise you to post an issue in https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues, and use .observes('parentView') for the as a workaround. (onParentViewChanged: function() { ... }.observes('parentView'))